# Centering a jFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to locate my frames at the center of the screen , I know that this code must work well:

```
Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
int x = (int) ((screen.getWidth() - getWidth()) /2);
int y = (int) ((screen.getHeight() -getHeight()) /2);
setLocation(x, y);
```

or this one :

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Dimension screenSize = tk.getScreenSize();
int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
setSize(screenWidth / 2, screenHeight / 2);
setLocation(screenWidth / 4, screenHeight / 4);
```

I have tried all the possible codes but I don't know why they don't work, the just move the frame to the bottom right corner of the screen I have used setRelative to null but again it doesn't work.

I could finally bring the frame very close to the center by multiplying the width by 5 and dividing it by something but I know that this is not the right way.

could anyone please explain to me what could be wrong ?

Problem Fixed :

solution:
I found the best way myself , if you ever come up with the same problem simply let the netbeans do that automatically by going to properties and checking generate center , forget about the stupid codes.

Comment: In the first approach, the size of the frame might not be known yet. You should probalbly [pack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29) it first.

Comment: I just make a Jframe in netbeans and try to center it , I don't any specific codes so there is no bug os something

Comment: If that is possible try to create empty frame and center it. Then gradually add components that you want to use on it and check when it starts to be displayed not in center.

Comment: I've done this for many times, it is not working I don't know why I doesn't work.

Answer (score 15):

The easiest way to center frame on the main screen (there are options if you have multiply screens) is to use setLocationRelativeTo(...) frame method with null as argument:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setSize ( 500, 300 );
frame.setLocationRelativeTo ( null );
frame.setVisible ( true );
```

In case that doesn't work - try this one (direct coordinates):

```
Dimension ss = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getScreenSize ();
Dimension frameSize = new Dimension ( 500, 300 );

JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.setBounds ( ss.width / 2 - frameSize.width / 2, 
                  ss.height / 2 - frameSize.height / 2,
                  frameSize.width, frameSize.height );
frame.setVisible ( true );
```

Last and "ultimate" example - it will display centered frame @ each available system screen:

```
public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    Dimension frameSize = new Dimension ( 500, 300 );
    for ( GraphicsDevice screen : getGraphicsDevices () )
    {
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = screen.getDefaultConfiguration ();
        Rectangle sb = gc.getBounds ();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame ( gc );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setBounds ( sb.x + sb.width / 2 - frameSize.width / 2,
                sb.y + sb.height / 2 - frameSize.height / 2, frameSize.width,
                frameSize.height );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
    }
}

public static List<GraphicsDevice> getGraphicsDevices ()
{
    List<GraphicsDevice> devices = new ArrayList<GraphicsDevice> ();
    for ( GraphicsDevice gd : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment ()
            .getScreenDevices () )
    {
        if ( gd.getType () == GraphicsDevice.TYPE_RASTER_SCREEN )
        {
            if ( gd == GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment ()
                    .getDefaultScreenDevice () )
            {
                devices.add ( 0, gd );
            }
            else
            {
                devices.add ( gd );
            }
        }
    }
    return devices;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried it, it is not working , could anything be wrong with the netbeans ??

Comment: @LoopMasters: my experience here has been when folks ask if something is wrong with NetBeans or Java, the chances of that happening are < 0.001%. The chances that something is wrong with your understanding of Java > 99.999%. If you can show us a small compilable runnable program that demonstrates your problem, we'll be better able to show you just where your mistake is. 1+ to Mikle Garin for his answer.

Comment: @LoopMasters It should work. It always work on any OS. Seems to me that you have some other code that changes frame location **after** that method call. Make sure you don't call setLocation/setBounds after setLocationRelativeTo method call

Comment: It just bring the frame to the bottom right corner and I can't understand why ??

Comment: @LoopMasters i bet if you try my simple code - it will work for you aswell. Just try it.

Comment: @LoopMasters: because you have a bug, likely elsewhere in code you're not showing us. For all we know you're trying to do all this before packing your JFrame. But who knows since it involves code not shown.

Comment: The only one way I could bring the screen very close but not exactly near the screen was to multiply the width by 5 and dividing it by 14

Comment: @LoopMasters setLocationRelativeTo(null) works if the size of the frame will not change after making that call. So make sure that this call is done after all your calls to setSize()/setBounds()/pack(), and of course you do not have a setLocation() after that.

Comment: @LoopMasters check 2nd example from my answer, it should work in any case if Java retrieve correct screen size. Otherwise that might be some specific platform bug inside JDK. Still i doubt that its a JDK bug

Comment: Sounds really weird this part doesn't work : /2 , I have to do this but it is not precise : *5/14

Comment: @LoopMasters Did you try the last two examples? Separately from your code ofcourse. I bet you have some problems in it. Just open new project and try there. Btw what is your OS?

Comment: I found something accidently by messing with netbeans properties, apparently it does that automatically, thanks anyway.

Comment: @LoopMasters Well, i bet it just does the frame positioning after frame becomes visible by adding an additional frame listener. Still its not a good way to do things in most cases

Answer (score 6):

It's enough if you use

```
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

According to [Javadoc for java.awt.Window.setLocationRelativeTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationRelativeTo%28java.awt.Component%29),

> If the component is null, ... the window is placed in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 3):

> I've already tried it, it is not working , could anything be wrong with the netbeans ??

maybe not wrong with netbeans

> I'm trying to locate my frames at the center of the screen

you can to try

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
frame.pack(); // or frame.setSize(int, int);
frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: `setLocationByPlatform` won't center the frame on many platforms. So this might be a good help diagnosing the issue, but not a proper answer to the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd bet dollars to donuts that you set the location relative to null / set the location through x and y coordinates before setting the size of the JFrame. If you haven't set the size yet, it is treated as 0x0, setting the dead center of it to the center of the screen. If you then change the size, it leaves the topleft corner where it was (the center of the screen) and scales it towards the bottom-right of your screen.

In other words, make setSize() come before centering it on the screen.

Everything else you did looks fine to me.